# Terragrunt: Provider "tfstate" not available for installation

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

When trying to provision resources for an application in an AWS Beanstalk einvironment with terragrunt, it gives:

```
Initializing modules...
- module.db
- module.db.db_subnet_group
- module.db.db_parameter_group
- module.db.db_option_group
- module.db.db_instance

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Checking for available provider plugins on https://releases.hashicorp.com...

Provider "tfstate" not available for installation.

A provider named "tfstate" could not be found in the official repository.

This may result from mistyping the provider name, or the given provider may
be a third-party provider that cannot be installed automatically.
```

terragrunt version v0.18.7
Terraform v0.11.14

Comment: Can you share your Terraform code?